# List<T> Sort uses Comparer<T> instead of IEquatable, Why?

Tags: .net, sorting, collections, equality

I have written a whole bunch of objects that are all parts of collections and on which I will need to do lots of sort and search.  On most of these object I have implemented and overridden the `Equals` method, `IEquatable` and `operator!` and `operator==`.

Now I come to wanting to use `List<T>.Sort` on an object having implemented all above and it turns out I need to implement `IComparable` to do custom sorting.

Why does Sort use `IComparable` and what is then the point of having `IEquatable` in all my objects?

Also what does `Object.Equal` overriding have to do with all this?

Comment: Thought experiment; you have three integers, `a`, `b` and `c`; you know that `a==b`, `a!=c` and `b!=c` (which is all the combinations available). Now: put `a`, `b` and `c` in ascending order ;p

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It can't possibly use `IEquatable<T>` to sort - knowing whether two things are equals doesn't help you rank them. However, it can use `IComparable<T>` if your types implement it, or any `IComparer<T>` (including `Comparer<T>.Default`) to provide a custom comparer object. The functional style (`Comparison<T>`) is convenient too, for ad-hoc sorting without lots of code:

```
list.Sort((x,y) => string.Compare(x.Name, y.Name));
```

but if you just want a simple *ordinal* sort, have your `T` implement `IComparable<T>`, and just use:

```
list.Sort();
```

Answer (score 7):

Equality can only give you a result of whether two objects are equal or not. It can't tell you whether `x` should come before or after `y` in the sorted order. Given only equality, how would you propose that `List<T>` should perform any sorting?

The point of implementing `IEquatable<T>` is for when it's *equality* which is important, e.g. in `HashSet<T>` or as the key type in a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`. Likewise, those couldn't be implemented efficiently using *only* `IComparable<T>`, as it wouldn't provide a hash code.

The two interfaces are basically used in different situations.

Answer (score 4):

Because `IComparable` allows to determine if an object is "smaller" or "bigger" than another object, whereas `IEquatable` helps finding out whether two objects are "equal".

The former is needed for sorting, because just knowing which objects are of equal value doesn't help you putting them in a specific order.

Answer (score 4):

Because sorting relies not on just equality but relative rank. In order to sort you need to know the position of objects relative to each other. Greater Than, Less Than, Equal.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as you can see in [the other questions about this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=IComparable+vs+IEquatable), `IEquatable<T>` checks for equality, while `IComparable<T>` introduces a rank which is needed for sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `IEquatable` interface you define an [equivalence relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation), but for sorting you need an [ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set).

Answer (score 0):

Equality tells you if two instances are equal. Comparability tells you how to sort them.

You override the instance version of `Object.Equals` when you know better than the runtime how equality works for your type.

Equality for reference types is defaulted to Reference Equality (same reference is the same object).

```
object o1 = new object();
object o2 = o1;

if(o2==o1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("These reference types are equal");
}

object o3 = new object();

if(o2 != o3)
{
    Console.WriteLine("These reference types are not equal");
}
```

Default equality for value types means that all member variables are equal. You should generally override Equals for value types, because you'll likely know better what equals means.

How this effects comparability is that comparability does somewhat rely on equality. In order to know what it means to be less than or greater than you need to know what equal to means.